# Is there a way to split strings inside a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to split strings inside a list but I could not find any solution on the internet. This is a sample, but it should help you guys understand my problem.

```
array=['a','b;','c','d)','void','plasma']
for i in array:
    print(i.split())
```

My desired output should look like this:

`output: ['a','b',';','c','d',')','void','plasma']`

Comment: I guess you need to add a pattern of how your desired strings look like

Comment: Please include the exact logic by which `d)` gets separated into `d` and `)`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses `re.findall` on each starting list term along with a list comprehension to flatten the resulting 2D list:

```py
inp = ['a', 'b;', 'c', 'd)', 'void', 'plasma']
output = [j for sub in [re.findall(r'\w+|\W+', x) for x in inp] for j in sub]
print(output)  # ['a', 'b', ';', 'c', 'd', ')', 'void', 'plasma']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response... But is there a way to do it  without using the regular expression library?

Comment: @UnknoWn_UseR you should create a new question then. this one has already been answered correctly